# I am not familiar with Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, python-re, python-regex

I want to allow only string that has "_" or "Alphabet

```py
import re 
    
expected_string = "new_tags"
note_allowed_string = "#new_tgas" or "#123new_tag"
   
# Wite and re that allow _ and Alphabet only
pattern = re.compile("_,Alphabet") #<- what to wright
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the "re" module? What means "Alphabet"? Only the ASCII letters A to Z or all Unicode letters? With or without digits? Uppercase and/or lowercase?

Comment: Alphabet and _ only

Comment: Again, what do you mean by Alphabet?

Comment: Letters A to Z (Uppercase and lowercase)  and Unicode letters ("_ "underscore)

Comment: So as long as you are working with strings, which are Unicode in Python 3, your pattern is simply `r"[AZaz_]+"` (`r"\w+"` could be considered, but it would also allow digits)

Comment: Or reverse it: `r"[^AZaz_]"` and check for no matches